# VBA Excel Can't get timestamp to appear on one sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Three macros. The StartSample module performs as expected. The PivotCheck is a custom function I wrote that works on my machine, but not once the file has been saved as another file (this is not unusual for custom functions, so I’m not overly concerned with that one). The FinishSample is the module that is driving me nuts. The timestamp should be a pretty simple thing to accomplish, and it works on the StartSample module. I cannot figure out what it doesn’t like to finish, and everything else in the code appears to function as expected.

1) This is StartSample code

```
Sub Start()
    ' Macro Purpose: Creates a new spreadsheet after applicant enters name and saves it with the applicant's initials as an identfier.

    ' Defines Variables.
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String

    ' Sets references.
    ' Creates a separate file on the desktop that is renamed with user's initials.
    TempFilePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
    TempFileName = Sheets("Results").Range("AppIn").Text & "MCDAII_Excel_Sample.xlsm"

    ' Optimizes macro performance.
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ' Saves file as separate file with applicant's identifier as filename on the desktop.
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName

    ' Unhides the worksheets with questions and relevant information.
    Sheets("Q_One").Visible = True
    Sheets("Definitions").Visible = True
    Sheets("Data").Visible = True
    Sheets("Q_Two").Visible = True
    Sheets("Q_Bonus").Visible = True

    ' Timestamp.
    Sheets("Start").Range("M1Time") = Now()
    Sheets("Start").Range("M1Time").Copy
    Sheets("Start").Range("M1Time").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Results").Visible = xlVeryHidden

    ' Saves changes and activates the Q_One tab for applicant to start sample.
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Worksheets("Q_One").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate

    ' Returns operations to normal.
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With


End Sub
```

2)This is the FinishSample code

```
Sub Finish()

    ' Macro Purpose: Saves applicant's sample to be reviewed later.

    ' Defines Variables.
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    ' Optimizes macro performance.
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ' Gives user one last chance to review work or continues to save sample for review.
    MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Clicking OK will close the spreadsheet and lock you out of the sample." & vbCrLf _
                        & "If you would like to continue working, please click Cancel.", vbOKCancel, "Final Notice")

    If MsgBoxResult = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf MsgBoxResult = vbYes Then

        ' Timestamp. <===PROBLEM: The next three lines of code don't function, even though they are identical to the StartSample module.
        Sheets("Start").Range("M2Time") = Now()
        Sheets("Start").Range("M2Time").Copy
        Sheets("Start").Range("M2Time").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 

        ' Unhides each sheet in the workbook (I thought), but it doesn't appear to affect xlVeryHidden.
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next

    End If

    ' Returns operations to normal.
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    ' Password protects, saves, then closes workbook.
    ActiveWorkbook.Password = "Milk"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: why do you need to do `= Now()` then `.Copy` then .PasteSpecial`? Seems like you could just set the value? Why the extra steps? What is the error you get?  `this is not unusual for custom functions` this does sound unusual.

Comment: I need the to copy the timestamp values to a hidden Results sheet to calculate the difference. I'm not getting any errors. The timestamp works and is visible on the Start Spreadsheet (M1Time) but (M2Time) doesn't appear. What should I do to correct this?

Comment: if you need to reuse the result of `Now` you should set it's value to a variable then use that wherever you need to. No need to copy/paste it.

Comment: note: `if` and `elseif` should be at same indentation level ... actually the indentation of your code is all over the place .... i'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

You're using `vbOKCancel` for the `MsgBox` buttons then checking for

```
 MsgBoxResult = vbYes
```

It's only going to be vbOK or vbCancel

Comment: Nice, and with that said, if the code above does fall into the vbCancel block screen updating and events won't get turned back on.